# Refreshing drop down options dynamically

Tags: ajax, database, laravel

I have to work on a form where I have to make drop-down for two fields, City and Educational Institutions. When a user selects a city, the options in the educational institutions get updated, i.e the institutions of that city appear. I am working on Laravel at back end. I have a little idea how things would work but I need to get in-depth understanding. Please guide.

Comment: You need to use AJAX for that. Go and do some research on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things I usually do when implementing a functionality look like the following steps:

**1**. Create HTML input fields

`<select class="action-select-city"></select>`

`<select class="select-education"></select>`

**2**. Create your jQuery change event

```
$('.action-select-city').change(function (e) {

    var val = $(this).val();

    $education = $('.select-education');

    $.ajax({
        // Your settings etc
        success: function (data)
        {
            // Clear existing options
            $education.html('');

            // Loop data and insert new options
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                $education.append('<option ... option>');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**3**. Create route

`Route::post('/something', 'SomeController@someMethod')`

**4**. Create controller and method

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{

    public function someMethod(Request $request)
    {

        // Always good to validate
        $this->validate($request, ['some rules']);

        // Get all educations in city
        $educations = .....

        return response()->json($educations);

    }

}
```

This solution is obviously not tested and the naming of certain things could be better. I hope this answer is helpful :)